# Application queries are not getting generated in trace file in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, trace

I am getting queries in trace file which are fired from Oracle SQL Developer IDE but I want to trace queries on Oracle database, which got fired from my java application.

I'm using `ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE;` command and using `tkprof` utility.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways of starting a trace in another session.

You can either use a login trigger that sets tracing in the session when it first logs on:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRACE_MY_JAVA
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
    IF USER = 'MYJAVAUSER' -- edit this condition to pick out your Java sessions
  THEN
    execute immediate 'alter session set events ''10046 trace name context forever, level 12''';
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END;
/
```

Or, if the session has already started, you can use `dbms_system.set_sql_trace_in_session`. Get the other session from `v$session`:

```
SELECT sid, serial#
FROM v$session
WHERE -- whatever you need to identify your Java application;
```

Then execute the proc:

```
execute dbms_system.set_sql_trace_in_session (sid, serial#, TRUE);
```

(Add the `sid` and `serial#` from the above query)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am getting error as "identifier 'DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION' must be declared"

Comment: Have you got grants on it?

Comment: I created one PUBLIC SYNONYM first but while grant i got  "looping chain of synonyms" error

Comment: @Jd Worries: Follow [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/resolving_pls_00201_identifier_dbms) blog in blog.oracle.com. If you still get errors create another question.